# Searchkick - Query String Query

Tags: elasticsearch, facet, searchkick

From this [page](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query), I am trying this:

```
[15] pry(main)> puts Post.search("price:>600").size
  Post Search (18.7ms)  curl http://localhost:9200/posts_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"match":{"_all":{"query":"price:\u003e600","operator":"and","boost":10,"analyzer":"searchkick_search"}}},{"match":{"_all":{"query":"price:\u003e600","operator":"and","boost":10,"analyzer":"searchkick_search2"}}},{"match":{"_all":{"query":"price:\u003e600","operator":"and","boost":1,"fuzziness":1,"max_expansions":3,"analyzer":"searchkick_search"}}},{"match":{"_all":{"query":"price:\u003e600","operator":"and","boost":1,"fuzziness":1,"max_expansions":3,"analyzer":"searchkick_search2"}}}]}},"size":100000,"from":0,"fields":[]}'
0
=> nil
```

While I do have entries with price greater than 600:

```
[16] pry(main)> puts Post.where("price>600").size
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE (price>600)
45
=> nil
```

Any advice why these two have different outputs? is it maybe the scaped character `"query":"price:\u003e600"`?

I also tried:

```
[37] pry(main)> Post.search(where: {price: {gt: 600}}).size
  Post Search (9.8ms)  curl http://localhost:9200/posts_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":100000,"from":0,"filter":{"and":[{"range":{"price":{"from":600,"include_lower":true}}}]},"fields":[]}'
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" IN (4, 9, 11, 16, 28, 35, 42, 5, 12, 17, 24, 29, 31, 36, 43, 48, 50, 1, 6, 13, 20, 25, 32, 37, 44, 2, 7, 14, 19, 21, 26, 33, 38, 40, 45, 3, 8, 10, 15, 22, 27, 34, 39, 41, 46)
=> 45

[38] pry(main)> Post.search(facets: {price: {ranges: [{from: 600}] }  }).size
  Post Search (10.4ms)  curl http://localhost:9200/posts_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":100000,"from":0,"facets":{"price":{"range":{"price":[{"from":600}]}}},"fields":[]}'
  Post Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" IN (4, 9, 11, 16, 23, 28, 30, 35, 42, 47, 5, 12, 17, 24, 29, 31, 36, 43, 48, 50, 1, 6, 13, 18, 20, 25, 32, 37, 44, 49, 2, 7, 14, 19, 21, 26, 33, 38, 40, 45, 3, 8, 10, 15, 22, 27, 34, 39, 41, 46)
=> 50
```

`where` makes what I expect: 45 posts. But I can't understand `facet`, could anyone help me with that?

This  question is also [here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/416).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
[42] pry(main)> Post.search(query: {query_string: {query: 'price:>600'}}).size
  Post Search (8.8ms)  curl http://localhost:9200/posts_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"price:\u003e600"}},"size":100000,"from":0,"fields":[]}'
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" IN (4, 9, 11, 16, 28, 35, 42, 5, 12, 17, 24, 29, 31, 36, 43, 48, 50, 1, 6, 13, 20, 25, 32, 37, 44, 2, 7, 14, 19, 21, 26, 33, 38, 40, 45, 3, 8, 10, 15, 22, 27, 34, 39, 41, 46)
=> 45
```

Although I am not understanding `facet` yet.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! I've been trying to figure this out all day, and spent a ton of time trying to figure out how to sue facet.